# Object with function that will delete itself

Tags: android, button

I have a class called LabelButton with an onClickListener. In my Activity class, when the user clicks a button it creates a LabelButton and a String. Then adds the LabelButton to the Layout.

Inside the onClickListener attached to the LabelButton, it calls setVisibility(View.GONE), which takes care of the LabelButton, but I also need to delete that String that was also created earlier.

Is this possible?

Comment: `String string = null;`? I might have misunderstood :p

Comment: Why do you want to remove String? Java has Garbage Collector for this purpose. As I know its good practice do delete/destroy only static members into the classes.

Comment: If you mean a textview instead of string, you can also call setVisibility(View.GONE) with that. Or else specify what you mean by string.